# Interpolation error using QGIS 2.8.3 with nearest interpolation function

Tags: qgis, python, raster, interpolation

With several point imported from `.csv` file containing the information of longitude, latitude and VALUE.

To represent the 2-d distribution of value, I want to interpolate the sparse point into 2-d contour figure.

Here is the distribution of the points, the background is China which I want to use as the mask shapefile.

[image]

Using QGIS Kriging or nearest algorithm dealing with the point data

[image]

They all come with same error: The data source is invalid.

How to fix it. I uploaded my csv data and shapefile here:

[(1) CSV containg lon,lat, value](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7FE0kxAL8kQWkRQRDczaXRCTkE/view?usp=sharing)

[(2) Shapefile of China](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7FE0kxAL8kQM2E2Qm51RzRUWFU)

Comment: Just suggestion: export your imported csv as vector layer and than try interpolation.

Comment: Have you considered upgrading your QGIS version to 2.18? Your data can be interpolated successfully using the SAGA tool **Nearest neighbour**.

Comment: My version is 2.8.3, that means I need to downgrade my QGIS version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using QGIS 2.18.2, you could:

1. Use the SAGA tool **Nearest neighbour** on your point layer.

   ```
   Processing Toolbox > SAGA > Raster creation tools > Nearest neighbour
   ```
2. Use the **Warp (Reproject)** tool to reproject the output of Step 1 with the mask of your polygon.

   ```
   Raster > Projections > Warp (Reproject)
   ```

---

Example using your data with a cellsize of 0.01 (note that the CRS used was the same as your polygon shapefile, `EPSG:4326`):

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the figure seems to be consisted of several polygons. Is there any way to generate the continuous contour map?

Comment: @HanZhengzu - The figure is the raster result of using the nearest neighbour analysis and then clipping it. If you want it more interpolated, you could lower the value of the cellsize for increased resolution. This would make the output more _continuous_ :)

Comment: @HanZhengzu - Or you could resample the result to a finer resolution using the GRASS tool **r.resamp.interp**.

Comment: @HanZhengzu - Most welcome! Hope you get the results you're looking for :)